# Every device's probability of failure during testing is 0.3. How many devices should be taken for a test to get a 99% chance that one failure occurs

Tags: probability

Every device's probability of failure during testing is 0.3. How many devices should be taken for a test to get a 99% chance that one failure occurs.

Kinda stuck over here, don't know how to move on.

Comment: If you test $n$ devices then what is the probability that all succeed (i.e. that no one fails)?

Comment: Are we to assume the failures are independent events? And is it important to get exactly 1 failure or are "1 or more failures" ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume each device is independent of each other, and define $p$ the probability of success. Then $\mathbb P(\text{At least one fails}) = 1- \mathbb P(\text{All succeed}) = 1 - p^n$.

Plugging in your information we have
\begin{align}
0.99 & = 1 - 0.7^n \\
0.7^n & = 0.01 \\
n & = 12.9.
\end{align}
So we require 13 devices to be 99% sure that ***at least*** one fails.